# Application keeps closing in background mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, background

I have a serious problem in my iphone application. It gets closed after entering in background mode (incoming call or even home button press)...I have inserted UIApplicationExitOnSuspend on info.plist and made its value false. But same problem exists...

Do you have any suggestions for this issue? I really need the application to be suspended not closed when entering to background mode...

Thanks

Comment: So it always exits when going to background? Are you getting memory warnings?

Comment: can you access your device crash log to see what is happening?

Comment: yes it is exiting every time i'm going to background...how can i access the device crash log?

Comment: What device are you using and what version of iOS do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See in your `Info.plist` file that you had selected the **Application does not run in background**, see this option must not be selected, if this option is selected means then remove that option from your **`Info.plist` file**, this will surely work I think and I hope this will help you

And Implement these Callback function

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;

-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
in your App delegate
```

Comment: i have deleted it but it is the same issue... ??

Comment: @Haythem: If your ios version is less than 4.0 means the background mode will not work, the application will directly quits in ios less than 4.0 so please check your ios version

Answer (score 0):

If this application was made from old templates of Xcode 3.x, than it probably don't have methods which used by system to check whether your app handle transitions to/from background or not.

Make sure what this methods implemented by your application delegate:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Comment: I have insert a NSLog in the 4 functions above...and when i press home button i have this log..

"Application did enter background"
"Application will terminate"